# My check method doesnt work properly on my phone, why? (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a normal Input-field where i type in my email address for example. In this Input field i have an onkeyup event, so when something is typed in it checks if the input of the user is correct or not (color of the input turns red if wrong and black if it is correct). It all works perfectly fine on the desktop browser but when i switch to my mobile phone´s browser it turns red if it is wrong but not black when its correct.

This is my code for the check:

```
/**
 * This function checks for the correctness of the param ownEmail (Inputstring)
 */
function checkmyEmail() {
  if (ownEmail.value.match("([a-zA-Z]|[0-9])+@[a-zA-Z]+\\.([a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]+$")) {
    warning.value = ""
    oEmailReady.value = true  //boolean if the string is correct or not
  } else {
    warning.value = "Type in a correct Email address!"
    oEmailReady.value = false
  }
}
```

This is my Input field in my html:

```
<input id="myEmail" :class="{'red': warning, 'black': !warning}" @input="checkReady"
             placeholder="email.privat@gmail.com" v-model="ownEmail"/>
```

I've tried different events like @input, @keyup, @keydown and a few other stuff like changing my check

Comment: Your phone could be any phone and any browser - there is no quick answer. Have you set up remote debugging for your phone? That way you can use Chrome's developer tools to see what is happening on your phone's browser, for example. Depends on the phone and browser of course.